# Disnake.py | Private Voice Channel - continuation of work

Tags: python, time, discord.py, voice, disnake

**CODE TASK**: When entering the main channel, the bot creates a new private voice channel with its own rights. If you exit the channel for 10 seconds, the channel is automatically deleted, **BUT** if you return to this channel during these 10 seconds, the deletion request is canceled and it continues to work until it remains empty for 10 seconds.

**MY PROBLEM**: I don't understand how to make the undo delete function.

**CODE**:

```
import disnake
from disnake.ext import tasks, commands
from asyncio import sleep   
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or('!'), help_command=None, intents=disnake.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if after.channel and after.channel.id == 'YOUR VOICE CHANNEL ID':
        category = after.channel.category
        guild = member.guild
        channel = await guild.create_voice_channel(name=f' {member.display_name}',category = category)
        await channel.set_permissions(member,connect=True,mute_members=True,move_members=True,manage_channels=True)
        await member.move_to(channel)
        def check(x, y, z):
            return len(channel.members) == 0
        await bot.wait_for('voice_state_update', check=check)
        await sleep(10)
        await channel.delete()

Bot.run('TOKEN')
```

I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 2):

You don't really have to cancel anything, you can simply `wait_for` user to join and put a timeout of 10s, when the timeout is thrown that means the user didn't join, you can then delete the channel.

```py
import asyncio


@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    channel = after.channel or before.channel
    if channel.id != YOUR_CHANNEL_ID:
        return

    category = after.channel.category if after.channel else before.channel.category
    channel = await member.guild.create_voice_channel(
        name=f' {member.display_name}',
        category=category
    )
    await channel.set_permissions(member, connect=True, mute_members=True, move_members=True, manage_channels=True)
    await member.move_to(channel)

    def check_leave(m, b, a):
        # check for specific user to leave the freshly created channel
        return m == member and b.channel == channel and a.channel is None and len(b.channel.members) == 0

    def check_join(m, b, a):
        # check for specific user to join the freshly created channel
        return m == member and b.channel is None and a.channel == channel and len(a.channel.members) == 0

    while True:
        # wait for user to leave and for the channel to be empty
        await self.bot.wait_for('voice_state_update', check=check_leave)

        try:
            # wait for user to join, if user doesn't join in 10s a timeout error is thrown
            await self.bot.wait_for('voice_state_update', check=check_join, timeout=10.0)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await channel.delete()  # delete channel, user didn't join in time and break the loop
            break
```